# Distinct Linq with Distinct SQL

Tags: sql, linq

I have SQL Statement like:

```
select distinct         substring(MFSOAM_Grp, 3, 3) a, MFSGRP_Description
from                    MFSOAM
                        left join MFCOM on MFCOM_Code = substring(MFSOAM_Grp, 3, 3)
                        left join MFSGRP on substring(MFSGRP_Code, 3, 3) = substring(MFSOAM_Grp, 3, 3)
where                   left(MFSOAM_Grp,2)= '03'
                        and MFCOM_Code is null
order by                substring(MFSOAM_Grp, 3, 3)
```

Then I tried to create on C# Linq:

```
var query = (from a in _context.Mfsoams
                          join b in _context.Mfcoms on a.MfsoamGrp.Substring(3, 3) equals b.MfcomCode into ab
                          from bresult in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          join c in _context.Mfsgrps on a.MfsoamGrp.Substring(3, 3) equals c.MfsgrpCode.Substring(3, 3) into bc
                          from cresult in bc.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          where a.MfsoamGrp.Substring(0, 2) == "03" && bresult.MfcomCode == null
                          orderby a.MfsoamGrp.Substring(3, 3)
                          select new
                          {
                              Group = a.MfsoamGrp.Substring(3, 3)
                          }).Distinct().ToList();
```

The result between SQL and Linq is different which is the Linq is wrong. Does anyone know what wrong on my Linq code?

Advice please.
Thank you.

Comment: In sql query you have 2 columns but in  the linq only one? so it make sense to be different.

Comment: Come on @sa-es-ir, it means I only need that column on Linq. But it should be doesn't matter right?

Comment: When you say ``wrong``, you mean the count of rows?

Comment: @sa-es-ir, yes....

Comment: So the columns are important in select distinct! You can check the generated sql query.

Answer (score 1):

As what I understand, the issue in your LINQ code lies in the comparison of `bresult.MfcomCode` with `null`. When using a left join in LINQ, the result for the joined table (`bresult` in this case) will not be `null` when there is no match. Instead, it will contain default values for the properties of the joined table.

To fix the issue, you need to modify your LINQ code to check for the absence of a match using a condition such as `bresult == null` instead of comparing the specific property (`MfcomCode`) to `null`. Here's the corrected LINQ code:

```cs
var query = (from a in _context.Mfsoams
             join b in _context.Mfcoms on a.MfsoamGrp.Substring(3, 3) equals b.MfcomCode into ab
             from bresult in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join c in _context.Mfsgrps on a.MfsoamGrp.Substring(3, 3) equals c.MfsgrpCode.Substring(3, 3) into bc
             from cresult in bc.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where a.MfsoamGrp.Substring(0, 2) == "03" && bresult == null
             orderby a.MfsoamGrp.Substring(3, 3)
             select new
             {
                 Group = a.MfsoamGrp.Substring(3, 3)
             }).Distinct().ToList();
```

With this modification, the LINQ code should provide the same result as your original SQL query.